# POST Routing Issue for Custom Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added a custom route, custom controller code, and actioned the custom route in the form, but I get an error regarding the route, even as it shows the route in error message.

The form/view is as follows:
    views/survey_request/confirmation.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @survey_request, url: survey_requests_confirm_path do |f| %>
  <p>Your Email Address: <%= f.text_field :customer_email %></p>
  <%= f.hidden_field :survey_token, value: @survey_request.survey_token %>
  <p>Your survey token: <%= @survey_request.survey_token %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

My relevant routes in the routes.rb file are as follows:

```
get 'survey/:id', to: 'survey_requests#confirmation'
put 'survey_requests/confirmation', to: 'survey_requests#confirmation'
put 'survey_requests/confirm', to: 'survey_requests#confirm'
```

In the survey_requests_controller.rb I have a method defined

```
def confirm
  #code here to confirm the users email and token
end
```

When I run the app, the confirmation.html.erb form shows up fine, to include the token passed to it. When I submit the form I get the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/survey_requests/confirm"
```

However when I scroll down on the same error page, it shows the route:

```
survey_requests_confirm_path    PUT /survey_requests/confirm(.:format)  survey_requests#confirm
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the defined route uses a PUT method and the form route uses a POST method.

Either change the route to be POST with `post 'survey_requests/confirm', to: 'survey_requests#confirm'` or add `method: :put` to the form `form_for @survey_request, url: survey_requests_confirm_path, method: :put` so the methods match.

Comment: thanks! that's what happens when you copy code from example sites without completely understanding it all.